# Задача Объединение последовательностей

Tags: c++

Объединение последовательностей
Даны две бесконечных возрастающих последовательности чисел A и B. i-ый член последовательности A равен i^2. i-ый член последовательности B равен i^3.

Требуется найти Cx, где C — возрастающая последовательность, полученная при объединении последовательностей A и B. Если существует некоторое число, которое встречается и в последовательности A, и в последовательности B, то в последовательность C это число попадает в единственном экземпляре.

Входные данные

В единственной строке входных данных дано натуральное число x(1≤x≤107).

Выходные данные

Выведите Cx.

```
Ввод:
4
Вывод:
9
```

```
Ввод:
1
Вывод:
1
```

```
Ввод:
2
Вывод:
4
```

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    uint64_t x;
    cin >> x;

    int i=1, j=1, a=1, b=1;
    int result = 0;
    while (x) {
        if (a <= b) {
            x += a == b;
            result = a;
            i += 1;
            a = i * i;
        } else {
            result = b;
            j += 1;
            b = j*j*j;
        }
        x -= 1;
    }
    cout << result;
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так и помогите исправить.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку вся последовательность не нужна, то искать k-тый член за линейное время как-то не фонтан.

Применим бинарный поиск, и найдём решение за логарифмическое число шагов

(точность вычисления целочисленных корней особо не проверял)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
uint64_t kth(uint64_t k) {
    uint64_t m, a2, a3, a6, cnt;
    uint64_t lo = 1;
    uint64_t hi = k*k;
    while (hi > lo) {
        m = (lo + hi) >> 1;
        a2 = (uint64_t) pow((m+1.0e-6), 1.0/2);
        a3 = (uint64_t) pow((m+1.0e-6), 1.0/3);
        a6 = (uint64_t) pow((m+1.0e-6), 1.0/6);
        cnt = a2 + a3 - a6;
        if (cnt < k)
            lo = m + 1;
        else
            hi = m;
    }
    return lo;
}


int main()
{
    uint64_t k;
    cin >> k;
    cout << kth(k);
    return 0;
}

>>
 10  64
 11  81 
 77  4225
```

Comment: @male23 Помогло ли вам решение?

Answer (score 0):

Возможные ошибки в коде:

Сначала, в `x` задается индекс `C`, который нужно найти, но затем в цикле `x` используется для отслеживания кол-ва оставшихся элементов `C`, которые нужно найти.

Далее в строке `x += a == b;` инкрементируется `x` когда `a` равно `b`, это неверно так как элемент должен быть в последовательности только один раз.

Ещё в строке `result = a;` и `result = b;` сохр. рез-т в переменной `result`, но в конце цикла нигде не используется и выводится посл. значение `a` или `b`, а не `Cx`.

И в конце цикла должно выводиться `Cx`, а не последний элемент `A` или `B`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    uint64_t x;
    cin >> x;

    int i=1, j=1, a=1, b=1;
    while (x) {
        if (a <= b) {
            if(x==1) Cx=a;
            i += 1;
            a = i * i;
        } else {
            if(x==1) Cx=b;
            j += 1;
            b = j*j*j;
        }
        x -= 1;
    }
    cout << Cx;
}
```

Вот ещё решение:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    uint64_t x;
    cin >> x;

    int i=1, a=1;
    while (a <= x*x) {
        i++;
        a = i*i;
    }

    int j=1, b=1;
    while (b <= x*x*x) {
        j++;
        b = j*j*j;
    }

    if(a<=b) cout << a;
    else cout << b;
}
```

или даже так:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    uint64_t x;
    cin >> x;

    int i=1, a=1;
    int j=1, b=1;

    for (int k = 1; k <= x; k++) {
        if (a <= b) {
            if (k == x) cout << a;
            i++;
            a = i*i;
        } else {
            if (k == x) cout << b;
            j++;
            b = j*j*j;
        }
    }
}
```

Здесь я использую цикл `while` для перебора последовательности `C` и проверки текущего элемента на каждой итерации:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    uint64_t x;
    cin >> x;

    int i=1, a=1;
    int j=1, b=1;
    int k = 0; // current index of C
    int last_a = 0, last_b = 0; // last element of A and B that was added to C

    while (k < x) {
        if (a <= b) {
            if (a != last_a) {
                k++;
                last_a = a;
                if (k == x) cout << a;
            }
            i++;
            a = i*i;
        } else {
            if (b != last_b) {
                k++;
                last_b = b;
                if (k == x) cout << b;
            }
            j++;
            b = j*j*j;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну, давайте посчитаем... 1, 4, 8, 9, 16, 25, 27, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 125 — так? Т.е. 9-е число - 49, 10 - 64. У вас (беру последний исходник, впрочем, первый страдает тем же, но еще и не компилируется) же 9-е число 36. Смещение, считали от 0? Ладно, пропустим. Но и 11-у, и 12-е числа у вас — по 64, в то время как по условию *Если существует некоторое число, которое встречается и в последовательности A, и в последовательности B, то в последовательность C это число попадает в единственном экземпляре.*

Comment: добавил код в ответ.

Answer (score -1):

Ваш код не корректно объединяет последовательности A и B. Вы используете две переменные i и j, которые указывают на текущий индекс элемента в последовательностях A и B соответственно. Вам нужно использовать только одну переменную, которая указывает на текущий индекс элемента в объединенной последовательности C. Вы также должны сравнивать элементы из последовательностей A и B, которые соответствуют текущему индексу, а не текущие значения a и b. И еще в вашем коде также используется переменная x, которая должна отображать текущий индекс элемента в объединенной последовательности C. И она используется как счетчик, который отслеживает, сколько элементов еще нужно найти в объединенной последовательности C. По моему мнению это неверно, так как в задаче требуется найти Cx, а не первые x элементов объединенной последовательности C. Я бы сделал так:

1. Определил одну переменную, которая будет указывать на текущий индекс элемента в объединенной последовательности C.
2. Использовать эту переменную для сравнения элементов из последовательностей A и B, которые соответствуют текущему индексу.
3. Использовать входное значение x для нахождения Cx, а не как счетчик.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    uint64_t x;
    cin >> x;
    uint64_t a=1, b=1;
    int i = 1;
    while (x) {
        if (i*i <= i*i*i) {
            if (x == i) {
                cout << i*i;
                return 0;
            }
            i++;
        } else {
            if (x == i) {
                cout << i*i*i;
                return 0;
            }
            i++;
        }
        x--;
    }
    cout << "Cx not found";
    return 0;
}
```

Тут использовал одну переменную i, который указывает на текущий индекс элемента в объединенной последовательности C. Сравнение i^2 и i^3 и выводит нужное значение Cx, используя входное значение x как индекс. Если x больше чем количество элементов в объединенной последовательности, то выводится сообщение "Cx not found".

Comment: Во-первых, не `iii`, а `i*i*i`, во-вторых, `x` - индекс значения в получающейся последовательности, так что `Cx` не может не быть найдено...

Comment: @Harry ты прав, х - это индекс значения в получающейся последовательности. Так что Cx должно быть определено. В моем ответе сообщение "Cx not found" было добавлено для случая, если код не сработает как ожидается, но в данном случае это не должно происходить и можно убрать это сообщение.

Comment: Как же его убрать? https://ideone.com/HCXaqL — вот оно, выводится...